# Forcing user to use the right generic method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

It could be a silly question, but please help to answer it. Currently I have an interface with 2 generic methods:

```
ValidationResult Validate<T>(T t);


IList<ValidationResult> ValidateList<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities);
```

What I want is if you want to validate an object, use `Validate` method; if you want to validate an array of object, use `ValidateList` method, pretty clear in mind and interface. But it seems user can also use `Validate` method for a list of object without any compiler errors (of course!). Any there ways to restrict them to `ValidateList` method? Thank you so much.

Comment: add <T> to your interface declaration

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, but you can pass a list to `Validate`, which is what he doesn't want

Comment: Validate<T> with one object is a subset of the functionality provided by the ValidateList<T> method. Why not just have one method specified in the interface IList<ValidationResult> Validate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities); where they can pass in an IEnumerable of one item if that is all they need validated. is there a strong case for breaking out the special case of one item?

Comment: Why should someone be prohibited from passing a list to `Validate`?  It's still an object; do you consider it *illegal* to validate a list?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727523/generic-not-constraint-where-t-ienumerable) is related and the answer is: No.

Comment: @x4rf41 This is validation service so actually i don't want to add <T> to interface declaration as it restricts my concrete class to specific type of validation, i.e B Validation Service or A Validation Service.

Comment: You can't have negative generic constraints (ie, everything except `someClass`}.  The only reason that generic constraints exists is to allow the compiler to know what signature to expect on the generic type.  It is not to provide the developer with design-time cues.

Comment: You want Validate<T> to validate object and a List is an object.  You want to negate and according to the link above from Tim that is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's kind of I'm actually expecting, negative generic constraints. Sounds like we do not have the answer here!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use generics at all here?  I mean, you'll have to write custom validation logic for each class you might pass to the method, right?  Seems like that kinda defeats the purpose of using generics.  Or else the entity classes themselves will have to contain their own validation logic, in which case it seems like the `Validate` method doesn't really have to care what type they are.  Could you just have separate overloads for `Validate(FirstEntityType value)`, `Validate(SecondEntityType value)`, and so on?

Comment: Hi @JeremyTodd this interface is exposed to outside. There are only one concrete class of this interface. In that class we use strategy pattern to pick the right validator one through typeof(T). This is internal control so you can have many strategies as you want but view from outside there is only one validation service.

Comment: @TuanHuynh I understand that, but any type constraints you specify for the generic method could simply be rewritten as the parameter type.  For example `Validate<T>(T value) where T : MyEntityType` could just be rewritten `Validate(MyEntityType value)` and save a little headache.  Unless the parameters passed to the method have to implement multiple interfaces not supported by the base class or something...

Comment: @JeremyTodd We also can do that way but we would end it up with headache when application grows up and cannot add new method as we go...

Comment: ...what about the Interface have a Validate `itself`, and an extension method to validade lists using the `itself` method?

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict a function to specific object types (and its derivatives) by doing something like this in the function declaration:

```
ValidationResult Validate<T>(T t) where T : ValidateBase, ValidateBaseOther
```

edit:

so in this  case, the function will only take objects that are `ValidateBase` or its derivatives, or `ValidateBaseOther` or its derivatives. You can of course just use one if you want

```
ValidationResult Validate<T>(T t) where T : ValidateBase
```

Comment: Note that they can still hardcast the object to invoke the other signature.

Comment: @Aphelion I am not sure what you mean. If the object is not of the type then the cast would fail right?

Comment: you can cast to the basetype with `(ValidateBase)` and thereby enter the non-other variant

Comment: @Aphelion What's the 'non-other variant'? If you cast an object `(ValidateBase)object`, and the object isn't a `ValidateBase`, then you'd get `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case, type parameter constraints are "and-ed" together, not "or-ed," so `where T : ValidateBase, ValidateBaseOther` won't compile unless `ValidateBase` and `ValidateBaseOther` are in the same inheritance chain (and I'm not sure even then), in which case you might as well just pick the most specific one.

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can't solve your problem (prevent `IEnumerable<>` from being passed to a generic method) with generics.  This is because you can't have negative generic constraints (ie., everything except `someClass`). The only reason that generic constraints exists is to allow the compiler to know what signature to expect on the generic type. It is not to provide the developer with design-time cues.

Aside from any unspecified external requirements, you can define your generic type at the interface, rather than the method.  This does not ensure that `T` cannot implement `IEnumerable<>`; however, it *does* ensure that `ValidateList` must accept a list of whatever is passed to `Validate`.  This means that `T` can be an array, but that would force `ValidateList` to accept an array of arrays.

If you leave the generic types at the method level, even though they both have an generic type named `T`, those types don't actually have anything to do with each other.

Generic type defined at interface.

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T>
{
    ValidationResult Validate(T t);
    IList<ValidationResult> ValidateList(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}
```

This would be implemented like:

```
public class SomeClass<T> : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    ValidationResult Validate(T t)
    {
        // Do something ...
    }
    IList<ValidationResult> ValidateList(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

And used like this:

```
var myInstance = new SomeClass<int>();

int obj = 5;
int arr = new [] {1,2,3};

myInstance.Validate(obj);
myInstance.ValidateList(arr);

myInstance.Validate(arr); // should throw compiler error
```

Comment: The only reason this is creating the desired result is because you're removing type inference and specifying a generic type, which is what results in the compiler error.  If the generic type you specified was `IEnumerable<int>` then the "errored" method would compile and the other two would fail.  Therefore this isn't stopping you from using a list in the `Validate` method.

Comment: Technically, that is fine because then `ValidateList` would require a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` which is a jagged array vs just an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since I don't want to add <T> to interface declaration because it restricts my concrete class to specific one. Think if we have 20 objects so we have to make 20 concrete class of that interface... The purpose of this interface is to validate various kind of objects. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ok, but see me last comment on the question.

Comment: @SteveKonves The point is that this isn't adding the assertion that the OP is asking for, and it's adding assertions that he's not asking for.  The only reason your example appears to work is because it's removing type inference and thus when you specified the generic type you, at that type, restricted the possible types each method could accept.  You can still pass whatever you want to either method by specifying the appropriate generic argument when creating the concrete class.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, but that type of assertion cannot be done with generics at compile-time.  However, it CAN be done with reflection at run-time.  My approach (using generics) was basically to ensure the correct relationship between the two methods, assuming that the interface was implemented correctly.

Comment: But that's not his goal.  The idea is to have two general purpose validate methods, one for sequences and one for non-sequences.  This only makes it harder to use such methods, not easier, it doesn't actually enforce the assertion the OP wanted, etc.  The main point here is that this clearly doesn't help the OP solve his problem (in addition to not technically answering the question).

Answer (score -1):

Since no better option was found:
Check if the type passed to `Validate` implements `IEnumerable<>`. If so, maybe raise an exception....

So, here it goes:

```
ValidationResult Validate(T t)
{
    Type OutResultNotUsed;
    if (typeof(T).IsOrInherits(typeof(IEnumerable<>), out OutResultNotUsed))
        throw new Exeption("glkjglkjsdg");
}
```

Extension Method to check if some Type Is or Inherits a generic definition.

```
    public static bool IsOrInheritsGenericDefinition(this Type ThisType, Type GenericDefinition, out Type DefinitionWithTypedParameters)
    {
        DefinitionWithTypedParameters = ThisType;

        while (DefinitionWithTypedParameters != null)
        {
            if (DefinitionWithTypedParameters.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (DefinitionWithTypedParameters.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == GenericDefinition)
                    return true;
            }

            DefinitionWithTypedParameters = DefinitionWithTypedParameters.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking for compile time validation.

Comment: Ok, answer "It's not possible", it will help a lot.

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question which specifically states it's not possible.  I have already voted to close the question as a duplicate of that other one, so there is no need to answer it.

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following:

```
public class MultipleValidationResults : ValidationResult, IList<ValidationResult>
{
    // stuff...
}

public ValidationResult Validate<T>(T t)
{
    if (t is IEnumerable)
        // use reflection to call return ValidateList<Y>(t)
        // (T is IEnumerable<Y>)
    // other stuff
}

MultipleValidationResults ValidateList<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities);
```