# Force generics to not be of the same type? Force generic to only be subtype of a given type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function which takes two generics `<C, M>`. I would like to force the `typeof(C) != typeof(M)`, is this possible?

I have read over the [MSDN page for type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) and it looks like I can only constrain in the "positive" case (`where C: <class>|<interface>|<generic>`) but not in the negative case (`where C: !<class>|!<interface>|<!<generic>`).

Another solution for me would be to force a generic type to be a subclass of a given type, but not that type itself. I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No - there's no such concept either in C# or in the CLR.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727539

There is no compile-time check for that. However, you can still do a runtime-check with `Type.Equals(Type)` and `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`.

Comment: Jon Skeet has spoken.