# A class is recursive - when this class gets implemented, the parent class becomes recursive

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Take the following example:

```
class Foo {
    public int SomeProperty { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Children { get; }
    // ....
}
```

If another class (e.g. `Bar`) implements `Foo`, `Foo` becomes non-recursive and `Bar` instead becomes recursive.

```
class Bar {
    public Foo { get; } // At this point Foo.Children doesn't make sense anymore
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Children { get; } // How can I enforce this part
    // ...
}
```

Currently I need to write two versions of every class, one with `Children` and one without. Inheritance makes this slightly less tedious but I can't statically guarantee that the requirements will be implemented correctly. I was also thinking about some kind of monad pattern with a higher kinded type `Recursive` but I can't wrap my head around it (especially since I just started learning it).

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I don't understand how this got marked as a duplicate. While I ended up with writing my own generic tree in the end, I didn't require it in my question and definitely didn't ask for a library. I was asking for general advice on how to approach the problem, where the solution I settled with ended up being a generic tree by chance. The fact that this question got closed **after** I provided my solution leads me to believe that someone read the answer, searched for trees on SO and then chose the first result, which doesn't help anyone. The "original" question doesn't even provide a solution to my question. This nothing more than laziness paired with the abuse of admin rights.

Comment: How does `Bar`"implement" `Foo` here?

Comment: There's no such thing in C# like "statically alter a parent class when there exists a child class with specific properties".

Comment: I really can't understand what are you aiming for

Comment: C# doesn't support this kind of variance -- the type of `Children` cannot change while inheriting. If you don't need inheritance, you can use `interface IFoo<T> where T : IFoo<T> { IEnumerable<T> Children { get; } }` and then have `Foo` and `Bar` implement `IFoo<Foo>` and `IFoo<Bar>`, respectively. You *can* actually combine this with inheritance if you use explicit implementations, but that gets a little messy.

Comment: Probably can't do this. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8727523

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out:

Don't make any of the classes recursive. Instead, create a generic class `Recursive<T>`:

```
public class Recursive<T>
{
    public T Head { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Recursive<T>> Children { get; }

    public Recursive(T head, IEnumerable<Recursive<T>> children)
    {
        Head = head;
        Children = children;
    }
    public Recursive(Recursive<T> source)
    {
        Head = source.Head;
        Children = source.Children;
    }
}
```

Next we need a way to transform `Recursive<Foo>` to `Recursive<Bar>`, which is pretty simple to implement (I used an extension method because this idea borrows from `IEnumerable` and functional programming in general; it just seemed more fitting):

```
public static Recursive<U> Select<T, U>(this Recursive<T> source, Func<T, U> selector)
{
    var head = selector(source.Head);
    var children = source.Children.Select(x => Select(x, selector));
    return new Recursive<U>(head, children);
}
```

And that's almost it. As long as you can force the very first construction to be `Recursive<Foo>` instead of just `Foo`, the issue should be solved. This part is probably implementation specific. I made the constructors of `Foo` private and instead provided a `RawFoo` class, plus a few construction methods from `IEnumerable<RawFoo>` to `Recursive<Foo>`/`IEnumerable<Recursive<Foo>>`.

If another object needs `Foo`, it can only get `Recursive<Foo>` easily. Sure, someone could call `myFoo.Head` but it's pretty clear that they're probably not getting all of the information they want. Instead, it's a lot easier to call `Select`, like the following example, which provides the programmer with an implementation of `Recursive<Bar>` instead of `Bar`:

```
var myBar = myFoo.Select(x => {
    var someBarProperty = // ...
    return new Bar(x, someBarProperty);
}
// typeof(myBar): Recursive<Bar>
// typeof(myBar.foo): Foo
```